# How do I set Bulma Variables when using Feliz.Bulma

Tags: f#, bulma

How do I set variables in Feliz.Bulma?
For example say I want to set the `$card-header-background-color` variable as described in the
[Card Component Documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/card/#variables)
I've hunted around on google and I can't find any examples or documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/variables/):

> To override any of these variables, just set them *before* importing Bulma.

So if you are importing Bulma in an SCSS file you could do this:

```
$card-header-background-color: #05164d;

@import "~bulma/bulma";
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the pointer I needed. I'd added the CSS link rather than going with the SASS library